# data-blueprint-id conflict on Nested form for polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a models A and B, both with a polymorphic association `has_many :xs, as: xable`

In the same view I have two separate forms, one for model A, and the other for model B.
But inside those forms there is a `fields_for :xs` such as:

```
nested_form_for A.new do |f|
  f.fields_for :xs do |g|
    ...
  f.link_to_add :xs

nested_form_for B.new do |f|
  f.fields_for :xs do |g|
    ...
  f.link_to_add :xs
```

The problem is that the `link_to_add` in the form for model B has the same `data-blueprint-id` as the form for model A.

This causes the `link_to_add` to create the wrong fields.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I had to get my hands dirty: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/pull/300

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You're truly a hero.